# Link of Nokia X Android Playstore

Tags: android

Can anyone post me the link of NOKIA X Android play store .As in this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=miwRfkQvISQ video they say as google playstore is different from Nokia X Android playstore

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [Nokia's Publish Store](http://developer.nokia.com/nokia-x/publish-your-app).

> Nokia X apps are distributed through the Nokia Store, a popular and
>   powerful store that delivers more than 14 million downloads per day
>   and growing, and supports operator billing in more than 60 markets.
>
> You can publish your app in Nokia Store with Nokia Publish Tool
>   through an easy publishing flow.

Answer (score 1):

You can [publish your Nokia X apps to Nokia store](http://developer.nokia.com/nokia-x/publish-your-app) with the steps mentioned. As mentioned in the 2nd step, you are required to have use [Nokia Publish tool](http://developer.nokia.com/nokia-x/publish-your-app) but for accessing this tool and uploading app, you must be a publisher.